org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported
i am trying to post a product with image and i am getting the above issue.enter image description here this is my product entity,
enter image description herethis is the controller,enter image description herethis is the service impl
i am getting this error
i tried through postman also but not working and also set content-type in headers manually but it still didnt work

Don't post code as links to images. Include the code in your question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
